# How can I translate the following SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have this query running ok in a stored procedure but now I want to do what S.P. does with C# with EF and LINQ, any idea?

I'm using .NET 6 in the MVC EF project.
I have my DB context working and entities for `Productos` and `AlmacenesStock` created.

The query:

```
SELECT s.ProductoId, p.Descripcion, SUM(s.Cantidad) AS Cantidad
FROM Productos p INNER JOIN AlmacenesStock s
ON p.Id = s.ProductoId
GROUP BY s.ProductoId, p.Descripcion
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that in your DbContext you have these `DbSet`:

```cs
public DbSet<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
public DbSet<AlmacenesStock> ProductoAlmacenesStocks { get; set; }
```

With LINQ query syntax/expression which has some similarities with SQL query.

```cs
var result = (from a in _context.Productos
    join b in _context.AlmacenesStocks on a.Id equals b.ProductoId
    group new { a, b } by new { b.ProductoId, a.Descripcion } into g
    select new
    {
        ProductoId = g.Keys.ProductoId,
        Descripcion = g.Keys.Descripcion,
        Cantidad = g.Sum(x => x.b.Cantidad)
    }
)
.ToList();
```

The above result will return the value with the List of `anonymous` type. If you have your concrete class to store the value, modify the `select` part as:

```cs
select new YourEntity
{
    ProductoId = g.Keys.ProductoId,
    Descripcion = g.Keys.Descripcion,
    Cantidad = g.Sum(x => x.b.Cantidad)
}
```

Recommended reading: [Query expression basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-expression-basics?source=recommendations)

Comment: Thank you Yong, I did exactly what you said and it works like a charm, thank you again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set up the relationship of Products and AlmacenesStock

```
var products = _context.Products.Include(product => product.AlmacenesStock)
                                .GroupBy(product => new { product.ProductId, product.Description }
                                .Select(product => new { product.Key.ProductId, product.Key.Description, x.Sum(almnacenesStock => almnacenesStock.Cantidad) });
```